# React and tables

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to display the data returned from an api in a tabular form.What is preferable:

Building a table from scratch and adding functionality like pagination, search and row select
or
  Using already built in components like react-table or react-data-table-component, MDBDataTable, etc

My requirement is, I just want to show the data returned from an axios call and also should have functions like pagination, row-select and search. Also, which component is best which will solve my requirement

Answer (score 1):

try this react table component ka-table https://komarovalexander.github.io/ka-table/#/overview
It has all required functionality. Works with both js and ts. And easy to start because of big set of demos